# Ruby on Rails Developed Applications

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, django

I'm looking to develop a desktop (not server) web application and I have been comparing Ruby on Rails vs Django. Question is, with Django the client needs to install Python 2.5, does the client need to install anything to execute a Ruby on Rails application?
Thanks....

Comment: Can you explain what you could possibly mean by a "desktop (not server) web application"? Can I ask you how exactly you would intend on building a "single story high rise"?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Django and neither Ruby on Rails to develop a desktop app. There might be some projects than can turn these projects to a desktop app but neither of them are built for Desktop App development.

These are web frameworks.

You could simply find these facts by some simple searches on the web.